# jQuery Mobile ignore swipe on scrollable element

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

Left/right swiping works nicely to navigate between pages in my mobile app.

On some pages though I have an element (`#timeline`) that can be touch-scrolled/dragged horizontally in iOS with native momentum scrolling.

But once I add the JQM swipe listener, any attempt to scroll the element horizontally is ignored and instead the attempt to drag the div triggers the page change.

I've tried altering (`$.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold`) in JQM's mobileinit but that doesn't help: even with a high value, the scrolling is slow and jerky and is likely to trigger the swipe event.

What is the best way to fix this?

The page is here: http://www.message-design.co.uk/CLO_guide_swipe/chapter_3.php

My code for the swipe is here:

```
// Handler for navigating to the next page
function navnext( next ) {
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", next + ".php", {
        transition: "slide"
    });
}

// Handler for navigating to the previous page
function navprev( prev ) {
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", prev + ".php", {
        transition: "slide",
        reverse: true
    });
}

// Navigate to the next page on swipeleft
$( document ).on( "swipeleft", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
    // Get the filename of the next page. We stored that in the data-next
    // attribute in the original markup.
    var next = $( this ).jqmData( "next" );

    // Check if there is a next page
    if ( next ) {
        navnext( next );
    }
});

// Navigate to the next page when the "next" button in the footer is clicked
$( document ).on( "click", ".next", function() {
    var next = $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "next" );

    // Check if there is a next page
    if ( next ) {
        navnext( next );
    }
});

// The same for the navigating to the previous page
$( document ).on( "swiperight", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
    var prev = $( this ).jqmData( "prev" );

    if ( prev ) {
        navprev( prev );
    }
});

$( document ).on( "click", ".prev", function() {
    var prev = $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "prev" );

    if ( prev ) {
        navprev( prev );
    }
});
});
```